# How to cast string to guid in classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, guid

Currently working on legacy application, need to pass json from webapi to classic asp page.This was fine, but have 1 property which is Guid I know we can use

```
Set tlib = Server.CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
strGuid = tlib.Guid
```

to create new Guid. But i am passing guid from json, how can we cast string to Guid in classic asp / VB script.

Note:No experience on VB script/classic asp.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. VBScript has no native GUID data type. So whatever you intend is not going to live or die based on that - a GUID in VBScript is a string and has no special properties. It feels like you experienced an issue and you think it relates to the GUID - so why not sketch a bit more of the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

can you post an example of your json structure, with your attempt at adding the guid to it. I ran into something similar to this not too long ago, and the following code worked for me when I wanted to store the GUID in the database:

```
 dim GUID, TypeLib : set TypeLib = Server.CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
 GUID = TypeLib.Guid
 GUID = Left( GUID, Len( GUID ) - 2 )   '-- strip off new line codes
 GUID = Replace( Replace( Replace( GUID, "-", "" ), "{", "" ), "}", "" )
```

just a thought, are you escaping the guid value BEFORE adding it to your json string?

Comment: From webapi i am sending json (which has guid),i want to convert received guid in asp page as json string to guid in classic asp.

Comment: An example of the code you're using would be helpful and I'm still not quite clear what you're trying to accomplish